# Malformed url Exception while running behavioural test cases

Tags: java, html, exception, junit, jbehave

I am trying to access a web page url from my behavioural test case. The following piece of code is used for it:

```
@When("the user opens the sys admin login page of jset application")
public void openSysAdminLoginPage() throws Exception {
    htmlPage = webClient.getPage("http://localhost:8080/jset/login.jsp");

    assertEquals(200, htmlPage.getWebResponse().getStatusCode());
    assertEquals("OK", htmlPage.getWebResponse().getStatusMessage());
}
```

This when run after the application is deployed on to the server, throws the following exception:

```
When the user opens the sys admin login page of jset application
10 Nov 2012 11:45:04,636 [main]ERROR com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage 
Malformed refresh string (found ';' but no 'url='): 3600;
```

I am able to access the page from the browser though. Have been stuck up with this for a while. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by commenting the following in my header jsp file:

**META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="3600"**